# Awk if statement with loop

Tags: awk

I want to sum the values of a column but I want to reset the average every 112 lines

what is wrong with this program

```
BEGIN{ sum=0;i=0}

{ sum=sum+$4
i=i+1
print i
if (i==112)
       print "total " sum*8 " average " (sum/i)*8  
       sum=0
       i=0

} 

END{}
```

The output is always 1

Comment: Don't you need braces around the body of the if?

Comment: yes, I forgot the braces, now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{
sum+=$4
}
NR%112==0
{
a=sum*8;
print a,a/112;
sum=0;
}' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the braces

```
BEGIN{ sum=0;i=0}

{ sum=sum+$4
 i=i+1
 print i
 if (i==112)
   {print "total " sum*8 " average " (sum/i)*8  
   sum=0
   i=0
   }

} 

END{}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it some:

```
awk '
{ sum+=$4
 i+=1
 print i
 if (i==112)
   {print "total " sum*8 " average " (sum/i)*8  
   sum=i=0
   }
}' file
```

---

You may also use `NR` instead of `i`

```
awk '
{ sum+=$4
 print NR%112
 if (NR%112==0)
   {print "total " sum*8 " average " (sum/112)*8  
   sum=0
   }
}' file
```

I see that with this it prints `0` instead of line number `112` but that could be fixed if needed.